# $\lim_{a\to\infty} \sin(a)$ if $\lim_{a\to\infty}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to find the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(\frac{2}{n^3})$, or actually to see if it exists.

Can I show that it is $0$ (or at least exists) with the reasoning that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n^3}\rightarrow0$ and that $\sin(0)=0$?

Is this reasoning correct, and if so, in the general case or only in my case?

I.e, is it true that if for a function $f(x)$ where $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\rightarrow0$, that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\rightarrow0$?

Comment: if $f$ is continuous at 0, yes.

Comment: I think the title should be $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(a_n) = 0$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ ? As for your question: the general result is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = f(a)$ if $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$ and $f$ is continuous. You can prove this in a $\epsilon-\delta$ fashion by combining the definition of what it means that $a_n\to a$ with the definition of continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin(\frac{2}{n^3}) = \sin(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{n^3}) = \sin(0) = 0$$
I used the Theorem: If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = L$ and the function $f$ is continuous at $L$, then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(a_n) = f(L)$$
So, since
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{n^3} = 0$ and the function $\sin(x)$ is continuous at $0$, then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin(\frac{2}{n^3})  = \sin(0) = 0.$$

Comment: **Note:** This is valid because we have a composition of two functions continuous as $n \to \infty $

Answer (score 1):

hint:
$\lim  \limits_{x \to 0} sin(x) \approx x$

also:

$\lim  \limits_{x \to \infty} sin(\frac{1}{x}) =0$

Comment: A notation that is more widely used is $\sin(x) \sim x$ as $x\to 0$ or $\sin(x)\sim_{x\to 0} x$. This is better as $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x) \equiv 0$ by definition is a number, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem:**

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a \in \mathbb{R}$ iff $\forall$ sequences $(x_n) \subset \text{dom}(f) $ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a$,

$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(a) $

Apply this theorem with $f(x) = \sin(x) $ at $a = 0$ with $(x_n) = \frac{2}{n^3} $

Take note that $\sin(x)$ is a function well-known to be continuous (take advantage of the if-and-only-if here)